# how to get the dignostic date which is closest to a specified repair date for a particular vehicle from the table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have created table data frame(tbl_df) called "Data1" (25000*4) as follows using dplyr:-
[Data1 sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56M78.png)

```
Vehicle.no   Repair date  mileage    Diagnosis date
23334         2011-03-03    5160       2011-09-29  
23334         2011-03-03    5160       2012-09-29 
23334         2011-03-03    5160       2010-09-29 
23334         2011-03-03    5160       2010-10-29
```

Here I have unique Vehicle.no, Repair date & mileage as you see in the example and since I have a different diagnostic dates for the same vehicle.no, it is recorded for the multiple times.

Finally I would like to have a table with single diagnostic date which is closest to a specified repair date for a particular vehicle no as follows:-

```
Vehicle.no   Repair date  mileage    Diagnosis date
23334        2011-03-03    5160       2010-10-29
```

I have already tried my level best to extract this information using dplyr as follows:-

```
Data1<-Data1%>% 
       group_by(Vehicle.no,`Repair date.x`) %>% 
       select(Data1$`Diagnosis start date`(which(abs(Data1$`Repair date.x`- Data1$`Diagnosis start date`) == min(abs(Data1$`Repair date.x`- Data1$`Diagnosis start date`)))))
```

Since I am a new user to R, I would need some help from you guys.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want this particular date? Is the month, year or day most important? Is it the earliest date? or the latest date in that year?

Comment: `select` picks columns.  To pick rows, use `filter`!

Comment: Hi akash87, I would like to gather the diagnostic date close to the repair date for the particular vehicle no. Usually first the vehicle undergo the diagnosis session and based on the severity, they will repair the component in the vehicle.

Comment: earlier diagnostic date to repair date

Answer (score 0):

I made a small adjustment to the column names just FYI,

```
library(dplyr)
Data1$Repair.date <- as.Date(Data1$Repair.date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Data1$Diagnosis.date <- as.Date(Data1$Diagnosis.date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

I think this next part can be condensed into 1 command but I am pressed for time:

```
Data1 <- mutate(Data1, date.dif = Diagnosis.date - Repair.date, date.dif = abs(date.dif))

Data2 <- filter(Data1, date.dif == min(date.dif))
```